# How to do a repartitionByCassandraReplica or joinWithCassandraTable with the pyspark embedded with DSE?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, datastax-enterprise

How to do a repartitionByCassandraReplica or joinWithCassandraTable with the pyspark embedded with DSE (datastax-entreprise 4.8)?

Answer (score 1):

First, `reparttionByCassandraReplica` is only available for RDD, not DataFrame (so consequently not possible for pySpark).

`joinWithCassandraTable` which suppose join push down to Cassandra is not possible with DataFrame (so consequently not possible for pySpark).

Sometimes, executing your Spark jobs using plain Scala code is still the best way to have optimization and perform join & predicate push down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm still confused: according Spark documentation: [A DataFrame can be operated on as normal RDDs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/sql-programming-guide.html#data-sources)

Comment: can be "operated", it all depends on what you mean by "operated".